# screen eges sprite kit swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm working on a new game and I faced a problem (making the edges of the screen act like walls !)
after some search I found this piece of code

```
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
```

but the problem is that only the bottom and the top of the screen are working as edges while the right and the left edges aren't working (when I throw a ball to the left it goes for a while -of the screen- then hit the edge and return !)

Comment: why all the answers speaks about delegate? I think your problem is not the delegate, for me you must check the size of scene, try self.view.frame or check the scale of the node

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set contactDelegate for physicsWorld in SpriteKit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32209725/how-to-set-contactdelegate-for-physicsworld-in-spritekit)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
```

and make sure you read over the [SpriteKit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH6-SW1) (Listing 6-1 answers your question).

Comment: This is the same as my code the difference is I wrote it with swift while you wrote it with objective-c !    ,    I tried your code though and it gives me an error !

Comment: @keloa - Have you set your GameScene delegate? GameScene()<SKPhysicsContactDelegate>

Comment: I didn't understand your question, if you mean prepare the edges to do something when the ball hits it that's not what I want (not at this point at least)
if you mean something else could you please tell me about it.

Comment: @keloa - you have to set the physics delegate in your GameScene in order for any physics to function properly. Look at this https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsWorld_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsWorld/contactDelegate

Answer (score 0):

You have to subclass your `GameScene` with the `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` in order to have collisions exists in your Scene

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: frame)
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
}
```

This question has already been asked and answered here: [How to set contactDelegate for physicsWorld in SpriteKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32209725/how-to-set-contactdelegate-for-physicsworld-in-spritekit)

Answer (score 0):

Check "scaleMode" of your scene.
Seems it is "AspectFill" and part of your scene simply is out of view.
If so - please try "AspectFit" value.
Docs with explanation: https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skscenescalemode